# Datepicker enable from specific date

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am taking date from one field..for example it has date as mm/dd/yy --> 07/04/2017

So in datepicker i want to enable from that date plus one day.

I tried with `mindate : $("#thatfielddate").val()`

But not working

Note: I want to disable past days from that date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this..

```
var strDate = new Date($("#thatfielddate").val());
strDate.setDate(strDate.getDate() + 1);
```

and add

```
mindate : strDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a Date object with the control's value, as shown below:

```
var date = new Date($("#thatfielddate").val());
mindate: date
```

second line of code should go into the initialization of datepicker.

Comment: Thanks, but the question is to plus one day.

Comment: Sorry. Missed that part :-)